# WordPress ACF custom taxonomy field display

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I'm fairly new to WordPress and using the ACF plugin for the first time.  I've created a custom post type with custom fields, two of which are of type taxonomy that are tied to custom taxonomies I set up specifically for this post type.  That all works great, but I'd like for the custom taxonomies to only show on the post form and not in the right sidebar since that's redundant and confusing for the editors:

[image]

Is there anyway to hide them in the sidebar?  I already checked categories and tags under the "hide on screen" option for the custom field group, but that didn't seem to make a difference.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'wpdocs_remove_post_custom_fields' );

function wpdocs_remove_post_custom_fields() {
    remove_meta_box( 'META_BOX_ID' , 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE' , 'normal' ); 
}
```

add in your active themes file -> functions.php

Following parameters:

META_BOX_ID: https://prnt.sc/3TLMZCHCak17

CUSTOM_POST_TYPE: add you custom post type

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this when I have a chance next week.  Is there any way to do it through the ACF admin interface, or can it only be done in the code?

Comment: yes, you can do it by open any custom post type and click on top right corner "Screen option" https://prnt.sc/0ApRvCXbr-8W uncheck taxonomy which not use in your dashboard https://prnt.sc/RG6-Snc8OCGv if not work this method use by code it will definitely work.